# Test Method for Custom Controller that references Lists in Loops

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, custom-controller

I have the following custom controller that is pulling some Lists and subsequently looping back through the Lists to do some sums on the values to display them on a Visualforce Page

I have only got 66% test coverage on this custom controller. Which seems to be missing any reference to the integer and Decimal fields referenced in the loop **for(Case cas: KGList) and for(Case casu: UnitList)**. I am not fully sure how to test for these in relation to the below code, any guidance would be great:

Controller:

```
public class IntrastatArrivalsList {

public Decimal openVolumeSumUnit{get;set;}
public Decimal AVGKGUnit{get;set;}
public Decimal openVolumeSum{get;set;}
public Decimal AVGKG{get;set;}
public list<Case> KGList{get;set;}
public List<Case> UnitList{get;set;}
public Case c {get; set;}
public IntrastatArrivalsList(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    if (!Test.isRunningTest()) controller.addFields(new List<String>{'id', 'ParentId', 'CaseNumber', 'Tax_Period_Start_Date__c', 'Tax_Period_End_Date__c', 'iArrivals_Price_per_Kg__c'});
        c = (Case)controller.getRecord();

    openVolumeSum = 0;


    KGList=[select Type, Id, iArrivals_Price_per_Kg__c, Status, iArrivals_Total_Net__c, iArrivals_Unit__c, CaseNumber, Tax_Period__c,
            iArrivals_Mass__c, ParentId, Tax_Period_Start_Date__c, iArrivals_Price_per_Unit__c, Tax_Period_End_Date__c 
        FROM Case 
         WHERE 
          Id !=: c.id
        AND
          ParentId =: c.ParentId
           AND
       Tax_Period_Start_Date__c <=: c.Tax_Period_End_Date__c
         AND
        (iArrivals_Price_per_Kg__c != 0 OR iArrivals_Price_per_Kg__c != null)
        AND
        Type = 'Intrastat Arrivals'
        AND
        (Status = 'Submitted' OR Status = 'Completed')
            ORDER BY Tax_Period_End_Date__c DESC LIMIT 12];

    for(Case cas: KGList)
        {
            Integer size = KGList.size();
            openVolumeSum = openVolumeSum+cas.iArrivals_Price_per_Kg__c;
            AVGKG = openVolumeSum/size;
        }


    openVolumeSumUnit = 0;

    UnitList=[select Type, Id, iArrivals_Price_per_Kg__c, Status, iArrivals_Total_Net__c, iArrivals_Unit__c, CaseNumber, Tax_Period__c,
            iArrivals_Mass__c, ParentId, Tax_Period_Start_Date__c, iArrivals_Price_per_Unit__c, Tax_Period_End_Date__c 
        FROM Case 
         WHERE 
          Id !=: c.id
        AND
          ParentId =: c.ParentId
           AND
       Tax_Period_Start_Date__c <=: c.Tax_Period_End_Date__c
         AND
        (iArrivals_Price_per_Unit__c != 0 OR iArrivals_Price_per_Unit__c != null)
        AND
        Type = 'Intrastat Arrivals'
        AND
        (Status = 'Submitted' OR Status = 'Completed')
           ORDER BY Tax_Period_End_Date__c DESC LIMIT 12];


    for(Case casu: UnitList)
        {
            Integer sizeUnit = UnitList.size();
            openVolumeSumUnit = openVolumeSumUNit + casu.iArrivals_Price_per_Unit__c;
            AVGKGUnit = openVolumeSumUnit/sizeUnit;
        }



    }
}
```

And this is my current test method.

```
@isTest 
public class Test_IntrastatArrivalsList {

static testMethod void testMethod1() 
{

    Account Acc = New Account (
    Name = 'Accordance Test',
    Industry = 'Retail',
    Registered_Street__c = 'Test Street',
    Registered_City__c = 'TestTown',
    Registered_Postal_Code__c = 'TE1 2ST',
    Registered_Country__c = 'TestCountry',
    Country_of_Establishment__c = 'a002000000OoWJ0'
    );

    insert Acc;

    Opportunity Opp = new Opportunity (
      Name='Test Opportunity',
      StageName = 'Prospecting', 
      AccountId = Acc.id,
      CloseDate = Date.today()
    );
    insert Opp;


    Case testCase = new Case(Subject='Test Case');

    Integer currentYear = system.today().year();

    testCase.AccountId = Acc.id;
    testCase.Related_Opportunity__c = opp.id;
    testCase.Country__c = 'a002000000OoWJ0';
    testCase.Status = 'Pending';
    testCase.Tax_Period_Start_Date__c = null;
    testCase.iArrivals_Total_Net__c = 100.00;
    testCase.iArrivals_Mass__c = 1.00;
    testCase.Tax_Period_End_Date__c = Date.newInstance(currentYear, 5, 31);
    testCase.Frequency__c = 'Monthly';
    testCase.Commission_Paid__c = 'Commission Paid';
    testCase.Deadline_Type__c = 'Set Date';
    testCase.Due_Date__c = Date.newInstance(currentYear, 6, 20);
    testCase.Data_Due_Date__c = Date.newInstance(currentYear, 6, 13);
    testCase.Submitted_Date__c = Date.newInstance(currentYear, 6, 14);
    testCase.Type = 'VAT Return';

    insert testCase;

    Decimal OpenVolumeSum = 1;
    Decimal AVGKG;

    List<Case> TestCaseList = new List<Case>();
    TestCaseList = [Select id, iArrivals_Price_per_Kg__c From Case Where Id =: testCase.id];

PageReference pageRef = Page.Intrastat_Arrivals_Lists;

Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

// create a new Contact standard controller by passing it the Case record
ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(testCase);

// now pass it to the extension
IntrastatArrivalsList obj = new IntrastatArrivalsList(sc);


    for(Case castest: TestCaseList){

       Integer size = TestCaseList.size();
        OpenVolumeSum = OpenVolumeSum + castest.iArrivals_Price_per_Kg__c;
        AVGKG = OpenVolumeSum/size;
    }

 }
}
```

Comment: You have hard-coded Ids and your test doesn't fail? What API version is your test class?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to make at least two more case records so that the filters for KGList and UnitList are satisfied by the test data. Once you have those records and construct your extension, you should obtain 100% coverage.